# Does Sitecore support SAML?

Tags: security, authentication

I'm aware of and have successfully used the AD module for numerous Sitecore implementations but I have a requirement to support SAML so that a non-AD based authentication provider can be used. Does Sitecore support SAML? If not, are there modules that would allow me to connect to various SSO providers?

Comment: I found this blog post from John West that lists all of the options but it is from 2011: https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/authentication-options-with-the-sitecore-asp-net-cms

Comment: Sitecore builds on top of the standard ASP.NET security platform.  If you can find a SAML provider for ASP.NET then you should be able to use that transparently to Sitecore. Most SAML provider I looked at did require a small amount of integration work though.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This will be natively supported in Sitecore 9.0, according to the public roadmaps. For now a solution might be to use this module: https://github.com/BasLijten/SitecoreFederatedLogin

See my blog on how to achieve this with Sitecore 9.0: https://blog.baslijten.com/enable-federated-authentication-and-configure-auth0-as-an-identity-provider-in-sitecore-9-0/

I explained completely how this works in my blogpost on federated authentication for Sitecore 8.x: https://blog.baslijten.com/how-to-add-federated-authentication-with-sitecore-and-owin/

Comment: I've read through that blog post but I'm stuck in an infinite loop where the ADFS server successfully authenticates me and sends me back, but the [Authorize] attribute prevents me from logging in (IsAuthenticated = false) and sends me back to ADFS (rinse, repeat).

Answer (score 12):

It might. There is a company claiming to have an option for it, but there is no direct download link and no way to easily verify the claim.

- https://www.ssoeasy.com/sitecore-sso/

That said; you might be better off, going through something like Gigya. Not only will you get SAML, but Gigya opens up for a host of other authentication modes and options. And there is a tested and supported Gigya module for Sitecore. This also satisfies your requirement for a module that allows you to connect to various SSO providers.

- https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/G/GigyaSitecore_Connector.aspx

I am not too familiar with the specifics of SAML myself, but here is the main entry point to Gigya/SAML documentation to give you an overview.

- http://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/SAML

Comment: Thanks Mark, I didn't know about ssoeasy.com - going to take a look at it.

Answer (score 9):

1) Sitecore 9+ natively supports SAML through Federated Authentication.
You have to configure it and write your own provider.
These links will guide you through this process for Sitecore 9:

- Usage in Sitecore - https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/federated_authentication/using_federated_authentication_with_sitecore
- Configuration in Sitecore - https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/federated_authentication/configure_federated_authentication
- Library to help you implement SAML (just reference it in your code) - https://www.nuget.org/packages/Owin.Security.Saml/
- Great blog posts on this topic to start with (with some more links inside to explore further :-):

  1. http://blog.nikkipunjabi.com/2018/02/sitecore-federated-authentication-part-1-authentication-google-facebook-identity-providers.html
  2. http://blog.nikkipunjabi.com/2018/03/sitecore-federated-authentication-part-2-google-and-facebook-app-and-the-custom-processor.html
  3. http://blog.nikkipunjabi.com/2018/03/sitecore-federated-authentication-part-3-sitecore-user-and-claims-identity.html
  4. https://blogs.perficient.com/sitecore/2018/01/23/federated-authentication-sitecore-9-part-1-overview/
  5. https://blogs.perficient.com/sitecore/2018/01/30/federated-authentication-sitecore-9-part-2-configuration/
  6. https://blogs.perficient.com/sitecore/2018/06/06/federated-authentication-in-sitecore-9-part-3-implementation-of-saml2p/ **Note** - This one is especially useful for this question.
  7. http://sitecore.badalkotecha.com/2017/11/federated-authentication-for-sitecore-9-integrating-with-azuread.html

2) Sitecore before version 9. Use solution provided in answers by @Bas Lijten or @Mark Cassidy.

Explore also usage of https://www.shibboleth.net/ as your Claims SAML provider in this scenario. Take a look on this article to troubleshoot some known issues here -> http://jockstothecore.com/federated-authentication-with-shibboleth-2/