# Sitecore 9 SSO implementation using SAML2.0

Tags: federated-authentication

I am trying to handle user authentication for sitecore from front end and I need to know if there are any steps\documents for handling SAML implementation in sitecore for now i do the following:

- created page to redirect to the identity provider
- created user resolver to map the returned response to sitecore user

Is there any other steps related to setting session or cookie to handle SSO in Sitecore?

Comment: Take a look on my answer to this question -> https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/3447/does-sitecore-support-saml. There is list of blog posts to help you out and answer your quesions. Could be that this is duplicate of that thread.

Comment: Yes i have a look on this thread and tried implementing this way but i faced 2 problems: is this implementation applies to adding backend button for external provider authentication only? , also i faced an issue that SecurityTokenReceived in SAML notifications is not firing, do you have any clue about this? i can share code with you as well

Comment: Yes this is only Federated Authentication for back end for log in into Sitecore and having user in Sitecore. Your scenario is more visitor login. If you need implementation for front end then you probably need to ask on different StackExchange network as this is not related to Sitecore

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is not relevant to Sitecore

Comment: I need to confirm that i understand your point of view, Do you mean for example that i will develop MVC application for authentication and just add this component in sitecore? but how will i authenticate user in sitecore, is the steps i posted above are correct for authenticating user in sitecore?

Comment: I am now kind of confused what you are trying to achieve because Question says something but your comments are saying something different.

Comment: Take a look on this code -> https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/tree/feature/v9/src/Feature/Accounts/code

Comment: This is I think everything what you need + links from first link in comments

Comment: It is a valid question. All posts and articles focus on Sitecore backend to be enabled with federated auth. Implementing frontend (i.e. website) SSO is still highly coupled with Sitecore, and its membership.